# Android Button overlapping other fragments during vertical scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-button

I'm using a gesture detector to determine when a user swipes downwards which in turn replaces the first fragment with the above fragment. Now, everything works fine, the first fragment is a frame layout and it disappears nicely. This is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/first_fragment">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#585858" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button"
        android:elevation="0dp" />
```

The problem is my "button1" is the only element that won't go away after replacing fragments. The second fragment's background is solid white, so even if the button isn't removed, it shouldn't be in the forground and yet it is. In my own troubleshooting I've tested other elements like checkbox and it disappears, however when I try other buttons they behave the same way thus leading me to believe its some messed up property in my buttons.

Also I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I have an animation when swiping up and back down, when I swipe from the first fragment, you can see a copy of the button which behaves as its supposed to and swipes down, but the first copy remains in place throughout the whole animation and is also clickable in the second fragment.

Does anyone know how I can make my button simply disappear along with the rest of its siblings?

Comment: Try removing the elevation tag from the button.

Comment: Wasn't that, that was actually a misclick from earlier thanks

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: @AjilO. No it is not

Comment: how are you animating it? Also by replace do you mean that the first fragment has been destroyed?

Comment: So the problem persists without the animation, but I'm using .setCustomAnimations(); and by replace I mean i'm using a FragmentTransaction and .replace(old fragmentID, newFragment);

Comment: Please post your XML of fragmentActivity